# Fixing Quotation Marks in Large Blocks of Text

Tags: punctuation, texshop

I am writing a casebook with a law professor using TexShop, and a large portion of project are legal cases, all of which have "quotes" and not ``quotes''

I know the programming difficulties of auto-replacement, but anything is better than doing this manually for four hundred pages of material.

I am not looking for a magic button, but what would be great is a workflow for converting quote marks before putting the cases into the latex document.

I know this is an old problem, and I know a perfect solution is not feasible, but something quick and dirty that works with copy and pasting large blocks of text would make me a very happy person.

Comment: I personally would just do a search&replace for ` "` (note the leading space) to only catch quotes in front of words.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

To replace all or most of the left-quotes, use something like this:

```
sed 's/"\([a-z]\)/``\1/g' < infile > outfile
```

Then the only quotes left will hopefully be right-quotes, so you can just find and replace them with two single quote marks.

Comment: While I read XKCD on a regular basis, I still don't know how to take a command line suggestion like that and actually use it to edit files.

Comment: So the sed suggestion wins the day!

Here is the final sed code I am using:
`s/"\([a-z]\)/``\1/g
s/"/''/g
s/§/ \\S \\ /g
s/&/\\&/g
s/\$/\\\$/g`


If anyone has any lines to suggest that would be great.
One that would be very helpful would be to auto delete 123*456 page references.

I used texhelpers sed program as a gui front end.

Comment: @LawMan: If sam's answer solves your problem, you should up vote it and accept it. It looks like you have another question as well, but I can't figure out what exactly you mean. In any case, you should ask it as a separate question, possibly on stackoverflow as it seems like it doesn't have anything to do with TeX (but I could be wrong about that).

Comment: Can't vote up, not enough rep.

Comment: I think it's better to use `\enquote{}` from [csquotes](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package. That way you can easily fix quotes whenever you change language, etc. Here is my exemplary style I had to define for Polish texts: `\DeclareQuoteStyle{polish}{\quotedblbase}{\textquotedblright}{\quotesinglbase}{\textquoteright}`